# In csv file search concern number for particular text in second column

Tags: linux, shell, csv, bind

I have main two csv files as follows:

file1.csv

```
731,dev-servers.com.,A,192.168.0.10
598,test-servers.com.,A,192.168.0.12
599,test1-servers.com.,A,192.168.0.11
```

file2.csv

```
dev-servers.com.,A,192.168.0.10
test-servers.com.,A,192.168.0.12
test1-servers.com.,A,192.168.0.11
```

I am looking for command to search in column2(file1) with column1(file2) and find the appropriate correct value and add to file2.

expected output:

file2.csv

```
731,dev-servers.com.,A,192.168.0.10
598,test-servers.com.,A,192.168.0.12
599,test1-servers.com.,A,192.168.0.11
```

Comment: The issue with your example is that producing the exact copy of file1.csv match the output. Then what do you expect (excepted `cat file1.csv`).  Perhaps an example with a file1.csv with a wrong IP address would be more adequate.

Comment: thanks i have corrected.

Comment: You still have an output file which is a copy of file1.csv. Then the added value of a solution is still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file1.csv has the content:

```
731,dev-servers.com.,A,wrong IP1
598,test-servers.com.,B,wrong IP2
599,test1-servers.com.,C,wrong IP3
```

and file2.csv has the content (a copy paste of your example):

```
dev-servers.com.,A,192.168.0.10
test-servers.com.,A,192.168.0.12
test1-servers.com.,A,192.168.0.11
```

The following Python script would print what you are expecting:

```python
numbers = {}

for lines in open("file1.csv"):
    columns = lines.strip().split(",")
    name = columns[1]
    numbers[name] = columns[0]
    
for lines in open("file2.csv"):
    columns = lines.strip().split(",")
    name = columns[0]
    try:
        print("{},{},{},{}".format(numbers[name],columns[0],
                                   columns[1],columns[2] ))
    except KeyError:
        print("{},{},{},{}".format('"?"',columns[0],
                                   columns[1],columns[2] ))
```

(Change the first line: python or python3 depending of your distribution).

Here, every line of file2.csv is printed with a number taken from file1.csv (same server name). `"?"` is printed if the number is not found.

Comment: thanks! any possibility in shell script not in python!

Comment: where you define output file.
above script is not working 

./script.py                                                                                                 [13/04/23 | 17:41:27]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/new/./script.py", line 15, in <module>
    print("{},{},{},{}".format(columns[0], name, t[name], address[name]))

Comment: Is this the only error message. Usually, we have **3** lines of error : Traceback, File, and TypeError... here I can't have a clue.

Comment: Note, my program will crash if the second file has not a line for each line of the first file, but this should not append with your files. It has been fixed (the adresses from file2 are used if present, else adresses from file1 are used).

Comment: Just type `python my_script.py > output.csv`. Note the program output col 1 (number) and 2 (server name) of file1, and 2 (address type) and 3 (address) from file2, with a joint on the server name. If the server is absent from file2, it output all the columns of file1

Comment: its good if the no of line on both files same, but i would like in such a way that it only looks content from file2, for example file 2 has 3 lines but assume file1 has 50 lines but those file2's lines are available in file1's. take 3 lines fist column value from file1 and add to file2.

Comment: Problem is if file1 has more data, i mean more lines of data and file2 is less just assume only 3 lines, after running output seems whole file1 content but but i need only matched content of file2.

Comment: Then you want the file2 with a number added in column from the file1. The number is taken from the line with the same server name. Can you confirm ? But What do you want if the corresponding line from file1 is missing. Your example is not very helpful since copying file1.csv is still a valid answer given the example. (And I suppose you want something else).

Comment: The script is updated... One output line per line of file2.csv.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a pure bash script solution:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=',' read -r col1 col2
do
   sed -i "s/^$col2,/$col1,$col2,/" file2.csv
done < <(cut -d ',' -f 1,2 file1.csv)
```

- `cut -d ',' -f 1,2 file1.csv` - cuts the first 2 columns of `file1.csv` file based on `,` separator
- `while IFS=',' read -r col1 col2` - reads the 2 cut columns into `$col1` and `$col2` vars
- `sed -i "s/^$col2,/$col1,$col2,/" file2.csv` - if a line begins with found `$col2` host info, adds `$col1` numeric info in front of it

Escaping of `$col2` may be required depending on the data. [Check for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern).